# python: компактная запись для выбора одной из двух переменных в зависимости от их значений

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, условия

есть переменные `l` и `r` являющиеся словарями

подскажите можно ли как-то компактно и красиво ;-) переписать данный функционал:

```
        if l == {} and r == {}:
            return {}

        if l == {}:
            return r

        if r == {}:
            return l
```

понимаю что вроде как и очень понятно и более-менее компактно, но может можно лучше

P.S.

минимум можно заменить строку 1 на

```
        if l == r == {}:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return l or r or {}
```

Без ифов. Если я правильно понял задание

Comment: да, круто!!!! а если бы было еще условие вернуть что-то когда `l` и `r` не пустые? Ну кроме того случая когда `return (l or r or {}) if l == {} or r == {} else xxx`

Comment: @eri достаточно `return l or r`

Comment: т.е. полный вариант `return xxx if l and r else l or r`?

Comment: @splash58 с учётом мутабельности это не  будет эквивалентно.

Comment: @Zhihar можно `r and l and xxx or r or l or {}` но с одним ифом смотрится лучше

Comment: @Zhihar Ставьте скобки, когда используете `and` и `or` вперемешку, иначе и глазом не видно в каком порядке считаются условия и не факт что они считаются именно в том порядке, в котором вы думаете.

Answer (score 0):

> Пример

```
if L == {}:
    print(L)

elif R == {}:
    print(R)
```

> Если в одну строку, тогда берем **or** так как при операторе ***and*** скорее всего выбьет ошибка, ибо один из предложеных вариантов может оказаться **False**

```
if L == {} or R == {}:
```